# Express JS : Handlebars "each" tag not displaying content

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, handlebars.js

I'm using Express JS and Handlebars package, and I'm actually facing something weird. I don't know if I missed something, I hope so, but I can't figure out what's wrong in my code.

I'm using : https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars

I can't make a `{{#each}}` statement work in my code.

Here is what I have:

**views.ts**

```
const Views = {
    config: {
        // views template configuration
        extname: '.hbs',
        helpers: {
            modulesList: () => {
                return appModules.modulesList();
            },
            foo: () => { return 'FOO!'; },
            bar: ['tic', 'tac', 'toe'],
            // bar: () => { return ['tic', 'tac', 'toe'] },
        }
    },
}

// Views is exported
```

**app.ts**

```
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const views = require('twiice/views.ts');

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs(views.config));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.set('views', './twiice/views');
```

**home.hbs**

```
<div class="col">
    {{#each bar}}
       <h6 class="text-light text-uppercase ls-1 mb-1">{{foo}}</h6>
    {{/each}}
    <h6 class="text-light text-uppercase ls-1 mb-1">Overview</h6>
    <h5 class="h3 text-white mb-0">Sales value</h5>
    <h6 class="text-light text-uppercase ls-1 mb-1">{{foo}}</h6>
</div>
```

Actually, `foo` is displayed on the last **h6** in the html code, which means the helper is loaded.

But the `each` statement is not displaying anything for `bar`.

Following the doc: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html

I can't see anything wrong :/

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm still learning! :)

Complete code here: https://github.com/Brawcks/twiice-ts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `bar` helper correctly.

[Handlebars helpers](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#helpers) are functions. When you want to use a helper in your template, you use it in a Handlebars expression, like `{{uppercase firstName}}`. In this expression, `uppercase` is the identifier of a helper we defined and `firstName` is a variable in our data context Object that will be passed to our `uppercase` helper.

The expression `{{#each bar}}` is telling handlebars to invoke the [built-in #each block helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each) on the variable `bar` in the data context Object.

However, `bar` does not exist in the data context Object because `bar` is not a part of our data, but a different helper that we have defined. So our problem is: How do we call two helpers within the same Handlebars expression?

Handlebars has an answer for this question; it is [Sub-expressions](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions). All it requires is for you to wrap your inner expression(s) in parentheses.

This means that updating your code to `{{#each (bar)}}` will be sufficient to tell Handlebars that `bar` is a helper that we want to invoke and whose return value we want to pass to `#each`.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/urhx3dqn/) for your reference.

Comment: Hello there ! Thanks for editing, I'm doing my best in english but i still do Errors.
But real Thank You for your answer, which is really clear to me and understandable ! I've edited my code, it's working perfectly for now. I was not understanding how helpers works, it makes sense to me now. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @VincentCfn: Thank you for your kind reply. I am glad I could help.